# Exchange items from one ListBox to another

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am trying to exchange the items in two `ListBox` controls, but only the word "(Collection)" is added. Why?

[image]

Comment: Don't add pictures of code, thanks,

Comment: Because you're adding a whole collection as a single item instead of adding each item from the collection individually. Either loop through the items collection and add one at a time, or use the `AddRange` method to add a collection of items.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding to a ListBox one element which is a collection of elements, `ListBox.ObjectCollection`.
The `ToString()` method is called on this object, returning the object type (`Collection`).

To swap the items, you could use a temporary storage that holds the collection of items of one ListBox, clear its `Items` collection, add the items of the second ListBox, clear the second ListBox and add the Items of the first one, using the temporary storage as source:

```
var itemsL1 = new ListBox.ObjectCollection(listBox1, listBox1.Items);
listBox1.Items.Clear();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(listBox2.Items);
listBox2.Items.Clear();
listBox2.Items.AddRange(itemsL1);
```

This works if the ListBoxes Items collections is not filled using the `DataSource` property.
Otherwise, swap the data sources.